# Adding external javascript file in javascript

Tags: javascript, electron

I am writing an Electron program and want to use some javascript classes in the main process. I would prefer to have those classes in different files and include them inside of the script.

I usually did this by just adding both, the script and the classes inside the html file but since it is the main process there is not html file.

**Question**
Is it possible to include an external javascript file in a different javascript file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `electron` is `node` based, you can use `require` both in your main process JS file and in any JS file your project uses.

```
// main.js or something
let myModule = require("./myModule");

// myModule.js
....
module.exports = function() {}; // or whatever you want to share with main.js
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a method called **getScript()** which can be used to load external scripts, https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

```
$.getScript('https://example.com/js/another.js');
```